# jsLint weird assignment error when casting

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc, jslint, jshint

I use google-closure compiler and jsLint tool for my JS code. Because closure compiler looks at JSDoc tags I need to cast variable to proper type or otherwise compiler will throw errors. Code below works ok (no compiler warnings), but when I run jsLint I get 'Weird assignment' error. Is there any other way to cast variable.

```
/** @return {Town|Village|Park|Metropolis} */
var getCurrentItem = function() {...some code}

var item = getCurrentItem();

if (condition)
{
    item = /** @type {Town} */ (item);  // 'Weird assignment' error occurs

    drawTown(item);
    updateTown(item)
}
else
{
    item = /** @type {Village} */ (item);  // 'Weird assignment' error occurs

    drawVillage(item);
    updateVillage(item)
}
```

I want casting to be done in one line and not on every function that I need to call!

Comment: See https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/weird-assignment.md It sounds like you need a way to document the type of `item` without reassigning it

Comment: Are you using `gjslint`? It's deprecated now: https://github.com/google/closure-linter

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are right. I know assigning variable to itself does not make sense in javascript, but I need it for casting. Unfortunately your link only works for window.location or other browser globals.

Comment: @johnlinp No. I am not using gjsLint.

Comment: @royalBlue I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to provide you with a few thoughts;

1) From [Writing Resilient Components/#marie-kondo-your-lint-config](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/):

> Here’s what I suggest you to do on Monday. Gather your team for half an hour, go through every lint rule enabled in your project’s config, and ask yourself: “Has this rule ever helped us catch a bug?” If not, turn it off.

2) [Closure Compiler has no issue with your code.](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540return%2520%257Bboolean%257Cnumber%257Cstring%257D%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520getCurrentItem%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257Breturn%2520true%257D%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540param%2520%257Bboolean%257D%2520p%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520updateTown%2520%253D%2520function(p)%2520%257Breturn%2520true%257D%250A%252F**%2520%2540param%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520p%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520updateVillage%2520%253D%2520function(p)%2520%257Breturn%2520true%257D%250A%250Avar%2520item%2520%253D%2520getCurrentItem()%253B%250A%250Aif%2520(condition)%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520item%2520%253D%2520%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257Bboolean%257D%2520*%252F%2520(item)%253B%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520drawTown(item)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520updateTown(item)%250A%257D%250Aelse%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520item%2520%253D%2520%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520*%252F%2520(item)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520drawVillage(item)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520updateVillage(item)%250A%257D%250A)

3) Just cast twice if you must:

```
drawVillage(/** @type {Village} */ (item));
updateVillage(/** @type {Village} */ (item));
```

4) If you're really quite concerned about avoiding repeating yourself, you can create a function that does the casting for you;

```
/** 
 * @param {Town|Village|Park|Metropolis} p
 * @return {boolean|Village}
 */
var getVillage = function(p) {
  if (p.somethingVillageSpecific) {
    return /** @type {Village} */ (p);
  } else {
    return false;
  } 
}
```

5) Lint with ES-lint + [jsdocs-plugin](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc).